# Add date and document properties in filename when saving

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a Word document (Office 365). When I save the document I want the filename to be as follows: CURENT DATE & STATIC TEXT & DOCUMENT PROPERTY(ABSTRATC) & DOCUMENT_PROPERTY(AUTHOR)

- CURENT DATE = yyyy.mm.dd
- STATIC TEXT = custom text I add and will always be plain text.
- DOCUMENT PROPERTY(ABSTRATC) = In the Word document, I've added many "Document Property) fields. In this case "Abstract". I want it in the file name.
- DOCUMENT_PROPERTY(AUTHOR) = In the Word document, I've added many "Document Property) fields. In this case "Author". I want it in the file name.

I have VBA code that does everything except adding the document properties in the filename. I am using document properties because I want my front page in Word to automatically fill in when you fill out page 2. So I want these field to be in the filename.

[image]

```vb
Public Sub FileSave1()
    Dim xDlg As Dialog
    Dim xTitle As String
    On Error Resume Next
    xTitle = ActiveDocument.BuiltInDocumentProperties("Title").Value
    xTitle = xTitle & "" & Format((Year(Now() + 1) Mod 100), "20##") & "." & _
        Format((Month(Now() + 1) Mod 100), "0#") & "." & _
        Format((Day(Now()) Mod 100), "0#") & " Report - Firealarm - Building A"
    Set xDlg = Dialogs(wdDialogFileSaveAs)
    xDlg.Name = xTitle
    xDlg.Show
End Sub
```

Comment: You already have the code to get the value of built-in properties in the code you posted. Just replace `Title` with the name of the property you want the value of.

Comment: Thanks, I saw that now xD Haven't really done this before. Just doing this to resolve this issue. It works now.